# How to set dynamic base route in vue router

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-router4

I need to set a dynamic base route(i.e. every route will follow this path) for my app.
e.g. `domain/t/{id}/...`
Here `t/{id}` is the base url part where `id` will be set dynamically.

In `createRouter` instance, there is a way to set base path but this accepts only string, no way to set dynamic values.

```
const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,
    history: createHistory('base-path')
  })
```

So, is there any way to achieve this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "base" implies common between all URLs.  There is [dynamic handling of route params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) already so you should handle any dynamic parts of your routing in the routes definitions.

Comment: thanks @yoduh for your suggestion but I need the base URL to be dynamic because my app depends on some global entities like tenant.